# Webpack: Uncaught ReferenceError: vendor_bd98b4ed288c6b156cc9 is not defined

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, webpack-2

I used the yo generator template described [here](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/05/02/angular2-react-knockout-apps-on-aspnet-core/) to generate an ASP.NET Core app with Angular2 as frontend. But randomly, after changing css files and saving them (which cause Webpack to reload), I got the following exception in the client console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: vendor_bd98b4ed288c6b156cc9 is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (external "vendor_bd98b4e…":1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 4cd8e17…:659)
    at fn (bootstrap 4cd8e17…:83)
    at Object.module.exports (eventsource.js from dll-reference vendor_bd98b4e…:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 4cd8e17…:659)
    at fn (bootstrap 4cd8e17…:83)
    at Object.<anonymous> (main-client.js?v=4atoLMuOmZwmyVdq2ky2bYoBjkmqmVnuPNSIFOD8Qjs:2625)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 4cd8e17…:659)
    at module.exports (bootstrap 4cd8e17…:708)
    at bootstrap 4cd8e17…:708
```

In the `dist/main-client.js` file I found the following lines:

```
module.exports = vendor_bd98b4ed288c6b156cc9;

/***/ }),
/* 1 */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

module.exports = (__webpack_require__(0))(0);
```

The error went away when I delete the entire `wwwroot/dist` folder and rebuild the Webpack packages. Then, the random string changes like this:

```
module.exports = vendor_9dc79ae12948ed5e4b95;
```

Seems like some sort of caching issue. What can cause this?

I'm using version 2.2.1 of Webpack.

Comment: I'm seeing this exact issue. Webpack 2.2.3. Did you figure a solution? Blowing away the wwwroot/dist folder and rebuilding didn't even resolve

Answer (score 0):

I was following a tutorial and had the same issue.  The tutorial stated that you need to update the webpack.config.vendor.js and re-run webpack after adding any new library

```
> webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js
> webpack
```

To help me in the future, I put this in my package.json under scripts:

```
"scripts": {
  ... Other scripts ...
  "start": "webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js && webpack && cross-env ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development dotnet run"
},
"devDependencies":{
   ... Other Dependencies ...
   "cross-env":"^5.0.1"
 }
```

Here is the tutorial I was following that explains it http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/

Hope this helps!